# An example of non commutative ring where $ab=0$ but $ba\neq0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a non commutative ring  where $ab=0$ but $ba\neq0$. Other disprove the statement.

I cannot find any way to disprove it.
I think such an example exists.
I was trying with $M_2\left(\mathbb{Z}\right)$ but could not get any example.

Comment: In reference to Jose's answer, matrices in general are the kind of "quantities " where $ba\neq{ab}$

Answer (score 7):

Take $a=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $b=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.